# Docker Permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create an rails application through docker.

my docker-compose.yml file is :

```
   mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.34
    ports:
      - "3006:3006"
    volumes_from:
      - dbdata
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=dev

  dbdata:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql

  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes_from:
      - appdata
    links:
      - "mysql"

  appdata:
    image: tianon/true
    volumes:
      - ".:/dock_rails_1"
```

Dockerfile is :

```
            FROM ruby:2.3.3
            RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs mysql-client
            RUN mkdir /dock_rails_1
            WORKDIR /dock_rails_1
            COPY Gemfile /dock_rails_1/Gemfile
            COPY Gemfile.lock /dock_rails_1/Gemfile.lock
            RUN bundle install
            COPY . /dock_rails_1
```

My Gemfile is :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '5.0.0.1'
```

I have also created the empty Gemfile.lock. 
After this run this command in my terminal:
docker-compose run app rails new . --force --database=mysql --skip-bundle

Every thing goes right. But I don't have edit acess to all the files created by docker.

When I  am trying to edit the database.yml file created by docker it is telling permission denied.

Please help me why I am unable to edit my files.

Comment: A good info would be to do `ls -l` on the file. It will give the exact permission accès right

Answer (score 0):

Just making a few assumptions here, hope I'm right..

Probably, the user you use inside the container is `root`
and the file is created under `root` privileges.

Try to create and use a user with the same uid and gid as in your host machine.

you can find out your hosts uid/gid by running on your host:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep $USER
```

change the containers user to hosts uid and gid in your docker file:

```
RUN usermod -u my_users_host_uid container_user  
RUN groupmod -g my_users_host_gid container_user
```

Comment: What is uid and gid here